# feeding multiple data frames into glm() and odds.ratio() - class

Tags: r

I've got a single data frame (mtcars) for which I can get the odds ratio (OR), including the 95% confidence interval, using the questionr package.

I'd like to group the mtcars data frame by the three-level gear variable, and get the same kind of output for those three new data frames as I got for the single data frame.

The problem is that odds.ratio() accepts glm lm class objects but doesn't accept list class objects. I tried placing odds.ratio() right outside glm() in MyFunc but it doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Code for a single data frame:

```
library(questionr)
data(mtcars)
reg2 <- glm(am ~ carb + cyl, data=mtcars, family=binomial)
odds.ratio(reg2)
```

Current code for multiple new data frames:

```
GearList <- split(mtcars, paste0("df", mtcars$gear))
MyFunc <- function(df) {odds.ratio(glm(am ~ carb + cyl, data=df, family=binomial))
}
lapply(GearList, MyFunc)
```

Comment: "MyFunc but it doesn't work." - can you add error message to your post?

Comment: Error in approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate ; In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50) ; glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Comment: I'm pretty sure your errors are the result of the very low number of observations in your split. I redid your routine with some of my own data and the `odds.ratio` computed without complaining. Your `GearList` includes three dataframes with 15, 12 and 5 observations.

Comment: I agree with @LAP, it looks like the odds.ratio fails trying to calculate the confidence interval for the data subsets of `gear == 3` and `gear ==5`.

Comment: FWIW - entire code can be replaced with `by`: `by(mtcars, mtcars$gear, FUN=function(df) odds.ratio(glm(am ~ carb + cyl, data=df, family=binomial)))`

Comment: tried using it on a bigger data set, got:  Error in UseMethod("odds.ratio") : 
no applicable method for 'odds.ratio' applied to an object of class "formula"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show that your code actually works:

```
df <- data.frame(group = factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = T), 1:3, labels = c("a", "b", "c")), 
                 int = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = T), x1 = rnorm(1000, 5, 3), x2 = runif(1000, 1, 100))

> head(df)
  group int          x1       x2
1     a   1  5.61526037 92.62681
2     c   0  0.55239463 96.64969
3     a   0  0.66831207 48.53553
4     c   0 -0.07698548 93.93554
5     a   1  0.57997037 40.25295
6     b   0  2.65677633 88.57560

reg2 <- glm(int ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = binomial)
odds.ratio(reg2)

> odds.ratio(reg2)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                 OR   2.5 % 97.5 %      p
(Intercept) 0.82392 0.59350 1.1421 0.2457
x1          1.03428 0.99280 1.0778 0.1073
x2          0.99954 0.99520 1.0039 0.8349

grouplist <- split(df, df$group)
MyFunc <- function(df) {odds.ratio(glm(int ~ x1 + x2, data=df, family=binomial))
}
lapply(grouplist, MyFunc)

> lapply(grouplist, MyFunc)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Waiting for profiling to be done...
$a
                 OR   2.5 % 97.5 %      p
(Intercept) 1.04981 0.59169 1.8637 0.8678
x1          1.00217 0.93118 1.0786 0.9537
x2          0.99645 0.98895 1.0040 0.3545

$b
                 OR   2.5 % 97.5 %      p
(Intercept) 0.77073 0.43629 1.3533 0.3659
x1          1.05588 0.98380 1.1346 0.1340
x2          1.00066 0.99310 1.0083 0.8647

$c
                 OR   2.5 % 97.5 %      p
(Intercept) 0.68406 0.38479 1.2054 0.1912
x1          1.04820 0.97757 1.1252 0.1881
x2          1.00169 0.99416 1.0093 0.6617
```

That said, I don't think the application in your example actually merits writing a custom function. You'd be better off just writing your code directly into the `lapply` call:

```
lapply(grouplist, function(x) odds.ratio(glm(int ~ x1 + x2, data=x, family=binomial)))
```

In my opinion, a function should seldomly contain data vectors as constants (only makes sense in mathematical procedures). When your aim is to loop over multiple datasets, variables or other objects, either write a quick temporary function into the loop (as seen above), or, if you think you'll be doing this kind of operation often enough in different combinations, write a function with more variables:

```
ORglm <- function(formula, dataset, family = "binomial"){
  questionr::odds.ratio(glm(as.formula(formula), data = dataset, family = family))
}
```

This way, you

a. don't have to load the `questionr`-package to use the function,
b. are free to change the formula without the need to edit the function itself, and
c. can even change the family of the `glm` you want to calculate.

You could even include more options if necessary. This takes only a few more minutes than your approach, but potentially saves you a lot of hassle in the future.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer the question of how to stop getting the error regarding calculation of the confidence intervals, as mentioned in the comments, here is a solution to calculating the odds ratio for a subset of data in a more elegant way (in my opinion at least):

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  # create list columns with each subset of data
  nest() %>%
  # create a new list column with the glm results from each group
  mutate(glm = map(
    .x = data,
    .f = function(x){
      glm(am ~ carb + cyl, data = x, family = binomial)
    }
  )) %>%
  # create odds_ratio list column
  mutate(odd_ratio = map(glm, odds.ratio))
```

As mentioned, this will still give you the error you got above, as the size of the data seems to be the issue rather than the method itself. If you choose a different dataset, this should work